# Pstricks \rput text on baseline

Tags: vertical-alignment, pstricks

In the following MWE, I intend to put several letters at different (x-) positions using `\rput`. As I want them to be on same "height" (like in normal text), I used the `\rput[Bc]` option. But it's not working. How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pst-all}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-10,0)(10,1.5)
\psframe[fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid,linewidth=0pt,linecolor=black](-10,0)(10,1)
\psline[linewidth=2pt,linecolor=white](0,0)(0,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-4.135,0)(-4.135,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](4.135,0)(4.135,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-4.467,0)(-4.467,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](4.467,0)(4.467,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-5.675,0)(-5.675,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](5.675,0)(5.675,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](6.037,0)(6.037,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-6.037,0)(-6.037,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](6.463,0)(6.463,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-6.463,0)(-6.463,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-8.859,0)(-8.859,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](8.859,0)(8.859,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](-9.689,0)(-9.689,1)
\psline[linewidth=1.1pt,linecolor=white](9.689,0)(9.689,1)
\rput[Bc](0,1.3){\small h}
\rput[Bc](-9.689,1.3){\small a}
\rput[Bc](-8.859,1.3){\small b}
\rput[Bc](-6.436,1.3){\small c}
\rput[Bc](-6.037,1.3){\small d}
\rput[Bc](-5.675,1.3){\small e}
\rput[Bc](-4.467,1.3){\small f}
\rput[Bc](-4.135,1.3){\small g}
\rput[Bc](9.689,1.3){\small o}
\rput[Bc](8.859,1.3){\small n}
\rput[Bc](6.436,1.3){\small m}
\rput[Bc](6.037,1.3){\small l}
\rput[Bc](5.675,1.3){\small k}
\rput[Bc](4.467,1.3){j}
\rput[Bc](4.135,1.3){i}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

Original (same "bottom line"):
[image]


My MWE (for example d is too low):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `[B]` option, not `[Bc]`, which doesn't exist. I took the opportunity to simplify your code with the `\foreach` command, and replaced `\resizebox`, which has the drawback of also resizing the font, by an equivalent `\psset{unit=0.84cm}`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,DIV=15,oneside,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pst-all}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\psset{unit = 8.4mm}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-10,0)(10,1.5)
\psframe[fillcolor=black,fillstyle=solid,linewidth=0pt,linecolor=black](-10,0)(10,1)
\psset{linecolor = white, linewidth=1.1pt}
\psline[linewidth=2pt](0,0)(0,1)\rput[B](0,1.3){\small h}
\foreach \y/\L in {4.135/i, 4.467/j, 5.675/k, 6.037/l, 6.643/m, 8.859/n, 9.689/o}{\psline(-\y, 0)(-\y, 1)\psline(\y, 0)(\y, 1)\rput[B](\y, 1.3){\small\L}}%
\foreach \y/\L in {4.135/g, 4.467/f, 5.675/e, 6.037/d, 6.643/c, 8.859/b, 9.689/a}{\rput[B](-\y, 1.3){\small\L}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]